# Vulnerability Concern From the Plugin or From Not Updating the Plugin?

Tags: plugins, security, updates

Our company website has over 40 plugins. That is a lot...way too many. However, each plugin serves a purpose.

When updating all plugins to the recent version we noticed parts of the website break. Yoast stops working, pagination stops working, the slider stops working, and so on...

I spoke with a friend that is a developer at a marketing company and they handle over 100 websites. They do not worry about updating the plugins for that very reason...things break.

Since a plugin is already installed on the website, is it really necessary to worry about updating all 40+ plugins?

Whether the plugin is active or not, in theory shouldn't we worry more about the plugin itself, and not so much if it is on the most recent version?
I would think that if a malicious attack came through a plugin, it would not be because it was not on the most recent version, but from the plugin itself using hooks to run special purpose code.

Comment: I don't think there is a definite answer to this. In general - meaning all software not just WP - the recommendation is to stay updated (at least for patches, and usually also minor version changes). The [WPScan team](https://wpscan.com/plugins) does a great job of listing vulnerabilities early on - being subscribed there and checking your specific plugins daily could be considered good practice to check if there is a known vulnerability about your specific version.

Answer (score 1):

At our company we use a good handful of plugins, most notably WooCommerce. The way that we have things integrated, and the systems built around that, mean that doing wholesale updates are usually going to involve a lot of fixes and debugging. But, in eCommerce, staying up to date with security fixes is a MUST. To that end, we've implemented a system of using composer to install our plugins at a fixed version, and then used composer patches to ensure we can continue to port security fixes into our codebase.

See [this blog post](https://mindsize.com/development/how-to-backport-woocommerce-security-patches-using-git-and-composer/) for a detailed explanation.

A simple guide would be:

- Add [composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) to your project
- Configure your project to use either a list of patches, or a patch list file as detailed in the configuration section
- Create some patches, we keep ours in a `patches` folder in the project root
- Run `composer install`

You can also use remotely-hosted patches, but we prefer to keep all of ours local to the project.

This system allows us to keep up-to-date with security fixes, and possibly bring in bug fixes (or fix things ourselves) without having to go through the trouble of doing complete version upgrades and possibly spending days fixing things to work.